# Whats the easiest way to move project Java from java.net to bitbucket

Tags: java, git, svn, bitbucket

Open source project currently hosted on java.net (SVN, JIRA) to encourage participation I want to move it to bitbucket (Git, can link to JIRA). This is the only data I need to transfer, things like the java.net mailing list are of little/no interest.

1. How do I transfer the SVN source to Git whilst preserving the history
2. What should I do about the JIRA issues ?

Comment: do any of these answers address issue 2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used this tool before to convert SVN to git.

https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git

All the installation and usage details are in the README in the repo. They have 10 example imports but in a nutshell you just:

1. point pass the SVN location to the tool
2. it creates a local git version with all the history intact
3. push it to your new remote git repo (if desired).

#### Edit:

Just found a duplicate so I'll flag this question. There's many answers to choose from there.

Comment: thx, I was hoping for answer that addresed java.net and bitbucket specifics rather than just git and svn

Comment: Those sites are just hosts. It's the technology that matters not the location.

Comment: this tool is linux only, I need something that works on Windows

Comment: @PaulTaylor, Did you try any of the suggestions from the linked duplicate Question? Did you get any working?

Comment: Hi, I looked at some of them and they all made it sound dead easy but then there were hidden steps that made it difficult. But in the end I did configure a linux machine and use svn2git like you suggested and it worked great, so thankyou.

Comment: Glad you got it working. If you stumble across enough Linux only solutions for issues in the future it may be worth the time getting and install Cygwin or a VM to give you a full *nix shell that you can use for those situations or even set up a dual boot or make the leap across to native Linux.

Comment: I do have a full linux machine, but is not my main dev machine because the application is a gui and the majority of my customers are Apple and Windows so its better that I can see the application how they see it, nor is it as laptop so not portable.